# Mouse wheel scroll does not work on the google chrome after applying the slimscroll

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, slimscroll

I have used the datatable library to render the users on the page( like https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/)
I have also set the height to 485px in the datatable.
Default scrollbar will be applied when I set the height in the datatable. I want to apply nice scrollbar in place of browser default scrollbar. So, I have used following code to apply nice scrollbar in the datatable.

```
jQuery('#listview_chats_wrapper .dataTables_scrollBody').slimScroll({
     height: '485px'
});
```

When I navigate from that page to another page, occasionally mouse wheel scroll is not working in any of the page on the google chrome.
It is working perfectly when I remove the code of slimscroll.
Can you please look into it?

Thanks in advance.